# python iterate over list elements for all combinations and perfom some action

Tags: python, list, csv, matrix

I have some elements in list and I want to perform some matrix operation for all combination of elements in the list.

for example if my list is `list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']` considering a 3x3 matrix like this:

```
0 0 0    
0 0 0    
0 0 0
```

so for example, combination of `A` `[(A,A),(A,B),(A,C)]` it should look like

```
0 1 1   
1 0 0    
1 0 0
```

incrementing `1` for each combination and excluding element's own combination `(A,A)`.

I tried something like this which is very basic but I am not getting the desired output:

```
data =[[0, 0, 0] for line in range(3)]    
x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for z in x:
    if z == 'A':
        if 'B' in x:
            data[0][1]+=1
            data[1][0]+=1
        elif 'C' in x:
            data[0][2] += 1
            data[2][0] += 1

matrix = "\n".join([",".join([str(num) for num in item]) for item in data])
print matrix
```

Comment: `"excluding element's own combination (A,A)"`: do you mean excluding it from the results of the combination operation, or just not incrementing your counter in this case?

Comment: Excluding i mean not incrementing the count . and i have not mentioned that it is always 3x3 matrix even if list = ['A','C'] . and i can structure the data differently as i get the list from text parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) is better suited in your case. Because it skips equal values. 
A simple example incrementing combination of A by one and combinations of B by 10 could thus look like:

```
data =[[0, 0, 0] for line in range(3)]    
x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
# we need the permutations of the indexes
xv = range(len(x))
for i,j in itertools.permutations(xv,2):
    #combinations of A
    if 'A' in (x[i], x[j]): 
        data[i][j] += 1
    #combinations of B
    if 'B' in (x[i], x[j]): 
        data[i][j] += 10
```

If you want to apply the same function to all permutations, simply skip the `if` part.

A slightly more advances version which adapts the size of the data matrix to the used letters and prints the resulting matrix could look like

```
import string
#ABC -> 012 map
abc = {i:j for j,i in enumerate(string.uppercase)}
#012 -> ABC map
abcinv = string.uppercase
#input
x = 'ADEC'
xm = abc[max(list(x), key=ord)] + 1
# data matrix
data = np.zeros((xm, xm))
# we need the permutations of the indexes
xv = [abc[i] for i in x]
for i,j in itertools.permutations(xv,2):
    data[i][j] += 1

#ensure diagonal is empty
np.fill_diagonal(data, 0)
plt.imshow(data, interpolation='none', cmap='Greys');
plt.axis('off');
```

gives
[image]

Comment: Hi Jakob this is what i wanted . But if we consider the matrix size is always 3x3 and list1 = ['A','C'] this will increment at wrong index as index of 'C' in list is 1 and in matrix its (0,2) for (A,C)and (2,0) for (C,A) right?

Comment: You are right. Is the matrix always 3x3 or is it NxN with N being the highest index in then complete ABC list? Can a letter appear twice in the input list?

Comment: No a letter cannot appear twice in list and the matrix is always 3x3 so in next iteration even list has [A,C] or [B,C] the increment should be in the respective (i,j) in 3x3 matrix.

Comment: So you are limited to [A,B,C] as input parameters? In the other comment you stated that you have 16 elements in the list??

Comment: Hi ya but your solution works well as it is based on NxN being N the highest index. i just modified line 2 and 5 for my data. But in general your script should perform well !! great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

how about `itertools.combinations`:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for i in range(0, len(list1) + 1):
  for j in itertools.combinations(list1, i):    # gets all subsets j
    # if j matches criteria, increment
```

Comment: hi yes that will work, but i have 16 elements in list and it makes some 240 combinations . so conditioning for each combination is difficult i, looking for some simpler way .

Comment: do you have to use a list or can you structure the data differently?

Comment: hi ya i can also use different data structure as i obtain them from another file